# Py goto site using input

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

How would I go about getting Python to send a user to a website using input? I have this code so far, using the webbrowser import:

```
import webbrowser
if cmd == "it.in":
    topen=input("<> Enter a web adress. Be sure to add the htpp:// or htpps:// at 
    the end."
    webbrowser.open(topen)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO
Looks like you forgot to close input statement with a ')'. Otherwise your syntax is correct
    topen=input("<> Enter a web adress. 
                 Be sure to add the htpp:// or htpps:// at the end.")
    webbrowser.open(topen). What is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry, rookie mistake :)